# network_info_plus problems to get SSID for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, wifi, ssid

I'm using network_info_plus in my Flutter project to get wifi name where a device is connected
It works for me on Android but not on iOS!

I then decided to test the example in their repo: https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus/example
and this works even differently:
Android returns all network data minus the SSID
iOS does not return any value
I have obviously given all the necessary permissions and I am using all the updated versions of Android Studio, packages and operating systems (Android 14, iOS 17.2.1)
I opened an issue on their repo but no one responds!
I also saw an inconsistency between the available release of network_info_plus which is 4.1.0 and the one published here: https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/ -> 5.0.0
Anyone have any ideas?

I tried the example on repo

Answer (score 0):

SSID is considered location information by Google Android.

So you should obtain one or more from the location permissions.

At the moment i dont know which one(s) as im laying under a palm tree right now ;-)